# Loop runs exactly 20 times, but MySql database inserts the data 16 times only

Tags: php, mysqli

I am developing a parser in which every time the parser will copy an image from URL to remote server, and save the details in MySql database. what i am doing is like this:

```
function scrap_photo($frompage, $permalink, $url, $message, $createdtime, $type, $imgid) {
    global $last_cron_timestamp;
    global $cxn;

    if ($createdtime > $last_cron_timestamp && $type == "photo") {


            $current_time_stamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
            $imgpath = "photo/".$current_time_stamp.".jpg";
            echo $imgpath;
            $fp = fopen($imgpath, "w");

            $handle = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5');
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
            curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

            curl_exec($handle);
            curl_close($handle);
            fclose($fp);


            $query = "INSERT INTO images (permalink, url, message, createdtime, imgid, frompage, type, photo_name, photo_path) VALUES ('$permalink', '$url', '$message', '$createdtime', '$imgid', '$frompage', '$type', '$current_time_stamp', '$imgpath')";

            mysqli_query($cxn, $query); 
    }
}
```

this function 'scrap photo' is being used to save the image to directory and to write the details in DB.

The problem that i am facing is, the loop runs for 20 times, this function is being called 20 times, and even the image count in the folder is 20, but in MySql database, only 16 query is getting inserted.

I can't figure out how or why, help!

Comment: I don't see a loop here.

Comment: did you consider unique keys?

Comment: yes, loop is there, which is calling this function everytime.

Comment: yes, unique keys also taken into consideration

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), from the help center.  Then, please edit your question to show a *complete* example.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your condition `if ($createdtime > $last_cron_timestamp && $type == "photo") {` passes for those 20 photos,
- use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to check if database returns errors as for example your values might be `null` while database doesn't allow them to be `null`.